# Parsing dhcp-parameter-request-list

Tags: dhcp

I am actually trying to parse the dhcp-parameter-request-list and see if it contains option 143 in the list. If it contains 143 option, then I have to respond with a 143 message with bootstrap server list.

But based on current eval options, I can only see whether option 55 exists in the request message. substring() also does not work, since I have to mention the offset and length to match, but 143 message can be anywhere in the parameter-request-list message.

Eg - option dhcp-parameter-request-list 1, 3, 43, 53, 54, 51, 58, 59, 143, 121;

Without knowing the offset, how can I parse this message and match if 143 option is a part of option dhcp-parameter-request-list?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.

Answer (score 0):

DHCP options are a sequence of *tag len data*. In order to check if an option is part of the DHCP message you would have to walk the option sequence until you either find the respective tag or the 255 (end) tag. Please not that *len* is the length of the data part not including the *tag* and *len* itself. Here is a C function for finding a tag in the option sequence:

```
unsigned char *find_option(unsigned char *option, unsigned char tag)
{
    // option points to the beginning of option sequence
    // tag is what we want to find

    while (*option != 255) {
        if (*option == tag)
            return option;

        if (*option != 0)
            option += option[1] + 2; // calc next option 
        else
            option += 1; // option 0 has no len field
    }
    return NULL; // tag not found
}
```

The parameter request list has option tag 55 and it is simply organized as an array of tag numbers requested. To check if 143 is requested, you do as follows:

```
unsigned char *opt55 = find_option(option, 55);

for (i=0; opt55 != NULL && i < opt55[1]; ++i) {
    if (opt55[i+2] == 143) {
        // do something if 143 is requested
    }
}
```

Error checking such as buffer overflows in bogus requests are omitted to focus on answering your question, but need to be considered in your actual server program. If you are not programming in C then the above is more like pseudo code but should help to understand the idea. This all is described in RFC2131 which I strongly recommend to read carefully.